# Identifying mystery line break / char(#) / control characters for removal (via php)

Tags: php, string, json, wordpress, str-replace

I have a client that has just moved a very larger, well established wordpress site to a new host. He has a series of JSON api's delivered via a plugin that have stopped validating (killing a mobile app).

I've identified the problem as that after the tags <a or <img are used in the WP admin, a mysterious line break is added.  Its not present in the WP html wyswig -- but the html src for the page also has the line break.

I've tried the following:

- replace: \n, \r, \r\n, char(10) (in various orders) -- No change
- replace: different char(#) -- No change
- using BBEdit to Zap Gremlins -- No change
- opening in VI to make sure that the line breaks are part of the file (they are - $ everywhere)

I'm open to suggestions on a method either identifying and removing these annoyances.

UPDATE:  After typing this all out, I realized I should check using a HexEditor.  The character is 0A.

EDIT:  Edited because part of my question was poorly formatted.  The character is being added previous to the JSON output.

Comment: How/where/at what point are you attempting this cleanup? Are you using WP-filter hooks?

Comment: How are you trying your replacement?  Are you doing a `str_replace('\n','',$subject);`?  Because single quotes will mean the two literal characters `\` and `n`.  If you are, then just use double quotes. `str_replace("\n",'',$subject);`

Comment: @nikc.org The cleanup is happening in the json ouput file.

Comment: @confused-demon Exactly the same?  I also tried nl2br and no change.

Comment: Ok, how are you generating the JSON-files then? Update your question with the complete process, that will help identifying possible stages where things can go wrong.

Comment: Ah.  Part of my question is missing.  So much for my editing abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing I outlined every known fact:

- It was not legacy,
- Deactivating all plugins did not resolve,
- It was not a rewrite rule,
- It was not garbage in - garbage out...
- It was repeating the issues on a child blog on the same wp build,
- a document at the root did not exhibit this behavior,
- it appeared to happen before rendering but after json_encode,
- it only happened for specific HTML tags (img, a, div, span (actually tags that have attributes like href or class))

After all that we decided that it had to be a plug-in and went through another round of checks.

It turned out to be the plugin wp-minify combined poor testing during the deactivation check.  The response was being cached and I assumed that there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a problem with UTF8-BOM? see http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en.php

Comment: I checked the feed using the linked web app and it reported no BOM.  Thanks very much for the tip, I've not heard of that previously.